# Sidekiq is processing a method that doesn't exist. Where to find calling of this method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

When I look to `/sidekiq`, I can see in the section called **Retries** that there's a job that has not been processed - failed.

```
Queue       default
Job         Order.order_report_for_manufacturers
Arguments   
JID         d25956cdd486335ecaf8a186
Created At  about 5 hours ago
Enqueued    about an hour ago
Retry Count 10
Last Retry  about an hour ago
Next Retry  about 2 hours from now
```

It's confusing for me, because when I search in my project the method `order_report_for_manufacturers`, the editor (TextMate) doesn't find anything. Then I though that maybe this method might be used in a CRON job, so I logged in to my Ubuntu server, run `crontab -l` but there's nothing (no rake task) that would use a method with such a name.

I tried also restart the server (and Sidekiq), but in a while this job (with this failed method) is there again.

How do I find from where is the method called? (it's not in the `Order` model).

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

Sidekiq log:

```
2016-05-15T14:23:40.910Z 25380 TID-163go0 Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass JID-d25956cdd486335ecaf8a186 INFO: fail: 0.006 sec
2016-05-15T14:23:40.910Z 25380 TID-163go0 WARN: {"class"=>"Sidekiq::Extensions::DelayedClass", "args"=>["---\n- !ruby/class 'Order'\n- :order_report_for_manufacturers\n- []\n"], "retry"=>true, "queue"=>"default", "jid"=>"d25956cdd486335ecaf8a186", "created_at"=>1463316907.739199, "enqueued_at"=>1463322220.9033682, "error_message"=>"undefined method `order_report_for_manufacturers' for #<Class:0x000000036eb740>", "error_class"=>"NoMethodError", "failed_at"=>1463316955.7728505, "retry_count"=>8, "retried_at"=>1463322220.9097943}
2016-05-15T14:23:40.911Z 25380 TID-163go0 WARN: NoMethodError: undefined method `order_report_for_manufacturers' for #<Class:0x000000036eb740>
2016-05-15T14:23:40.911Z 25380 TID-163go0 WARN: /home/deployer/apps/myapp-production/shared/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:26:in `method_missing'
```

**EDIT2:**
I am using Sidekiq as an Upstart service (Ubuntu server). I am just running the command `ps aux | grep '[s]idekiq'`, I get this output:

```
deployer  6647  0.4 15.8 1162920 611080 ?      Ssl  May03  73:59 sidekiq 4.1.1 myapp-production [0 of 25 busy]
deployer  6659  0.4 18.2 1132336 702620 ?      Ssl  May03  75:06 sidekiq 4.1.1 myapp-production [0 of 25 busy]
deployer 25380  0.4  8.5 936444 329260 ?       Ssl  May14   5:14 sidekiq 4.1.1 myapp-production [0 of 25 busy]
```

I don't know why Sidekiq is there three times; I know that I restarted sidekiq yesterday (`sudo stop sidekiq index=0` and `sudo start sidekiq index=0`) - that's the one on the third line.

What are the first two rows I have no idea. Redis is running on a separated server and communicate with this server (where is the application + Sidekiq).

Comment: This may sound overly obvious - and apologies if you've done this already - but have you explored the log file (e.g., `app_directory/log/sidekiq.log`)? It should, due to the error, offer a stack trace that will allow you to see the chain of calls leading up to the error.

Comment: Yes, I have looked there - will update the OP. OP updated - added the the relevant sidekiq log.

Comment: Perhaps there are multiple apps trying to use sidekiq on a single server? Sidekiq uses Redis for the queue storage which is shared among all processes on the server so unless properly configured, any process can add a job to the a queue.

Comment: Thanks, @BoraMa, added more info to the OP. There's only one app.

Comment: If you are having trouble with a job retrying then I recommend using the Sidekiq API to clear the Retry queue. (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#retries) If the job comes back after you have cleared the queue then it is still being called somewhere. Also, if you have three running instances of Sidekiq then the old ones did not properly shut down. You should `kill 6647` and `kill 6659`.